# Doctrine Inheritance and user types

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

im new to Doctrine and ORM in general.

I got 4 user types (Admin, Caretaker, Child, Personal).
They all got some of the same columns (id, name, mail, password, created, type & group)
and they got a few columns special to each of them (Caretaker has a child id etc.)

I'm not quite sure how i should map this.
Like should i make my user types extend the User, giving the Child table the user columns, or what would be best practice here?

I assume the the option to use extend would force some more work when doing a login?

**User.php**

```
/**
 * @MappedSuperclass
 * @Entity @Table(name="users")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     **/
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     **/
    protected $name;
    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     **/
    protected $mail;
    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     **/
    protected $password;
    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     **/
    protected $created;
    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     **/
    protected $lastlogin;
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group")
     * @JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $group;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Type")
     * @JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $type;

    public function __construct() {}

    public function getId() { return $this->id; }

    public function getName() { return $this->name; }

    public function getMail() { return $this->mail; }

    public function getCreated() { return $this->mail; }

    public function getLastLogin() { return $this->lastlogin; }

    public function getGroup() { return $this->group; }

    public function getType() { return $this->type; }

    public function setName($name) { $this->name = $name; }

    public function setMail($mail) { $this->mail = $mail; }

    public function setCreated() { $this->created = new DateTime("now"); }

    public function setLastLogin() { $this->lastlogin = new DateTime("now"); }

    public function setGroup($group) { $this->group = $group; }

    public function setType($type) { $this->type = $type; }
}
```

**Child.php**

```
// src/Child.php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="child")
 */
class Child extends User
{
    /**
     * @Id @OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $image;
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User")
     * @JoinTable(name="child_Contacts",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="child_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="contact_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $currentContacts;
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Alarm", mappedBy="child")
     */
    protected $alarms;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->alarms = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Comment: From my experience: If these 4 entities are mostly the same,  i suggest to use one database table with superset of all needed attributes and use one entity in Doctrine and solve different handling on application level and not database level. Usually later you wil find out that somebody is for example both Personal and Caretaker and then problems with structured solution begin...

Comment: @Miro Thanks, never thought about that, sounds like an easier way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily solve this problem with doctrine and `InheritanceType` mapping.

Basically, you can do something like this :

```
/**
 * @MappedSuperclass
 * @Entity @Table(name="users")
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"Admin" = "Admin", "Caretaker" = "Caretaker", "Child" = "Child", "Personal" = "Personal"})
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     **/
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     **/
    protected $name;
    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     **/
    protected $mail;
    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     **/
    protected $password;
    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     **/
    protected $created;
    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     **/
    protected $lastlogin;
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group")
     * @JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $group;
}
```

And then, in each 4 different classes,

```
// src/Child.php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="child")
 */
class Child extends User
{
    /**
     * @Id @OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $image;
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User")
     * @JoinTable(name="child_Contacts",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="child_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="contact_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $currentContacts;
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Alarm", mappedBy="child")
     */
    protected $alarms;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->alarms = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

The doctrine docs is really good for this problem : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

And you don't need an extra check at login because doctrine create automatically the right class for you.

Comment: Forgot to get answer in, Miro's comment helped me reach this solution aswell.

but now theres an answer for others in the same situation to see Thanks